# Command \@ already defined when using journal style file

Tags: macros, markdown, rmarkdown

I am trying to compile an (R) markdown document that includes a journal style file. The following line produces the following error:

```
\newcommand\@titlenote{}
%! LaTeX Error: Command \@ already defined.
%               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

I'm not really familiar with macros so I don't know if this should be valid or not! I know that it is used later in the style file:

```
\let\footnote\thanks 
{\fontsize{20}{22}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \@title \par {\small{\@titlenote}} }
\vskip 1.5em
{\@author \par}
\end{minipage}
\vskip 1em \par
}
```

In case this isn't enough information, this is my full setup. This markdown in `foo.Rmd`

```
---
title: "The foo bar: a novel metal bar for holding fire doors"
author:
- name: Bar Baz
  affiliation: 
  - Bar Institute
  email: foo@bar.baz
abstract: |
  Lorem ipsum dolor.
keywords: Foo, Bar, Baz
output: 
  BiocWorkflowTools::f1000_article:
    includes:
      in_header: f1000_styles.sty
urlcolor: Orange
subparagraph: yes
geometry: "hmargin=1.8cm,vmargin=2.2cm"
---

Lorem ipsum dolor.
```

where `f1000_styles.sty` is available [here](https://github.com/grimbough/BiocWorkflowTools/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/f1000_article/skeleton/f1000_styles.sty).

This document can be built by running `rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd")`.
Sorry that it's a bit roundabout. This is as close to minimal as I managed.

Comment: Change `\newcommand\@titlenote{}` to `\makeatletter\newcommand\@titlenote{}\makeatother`

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly (make it an answer if you like). I find it weird that this is in a style file recommended by this software package - is there a way this *could* compile without error?

Comment: If you would use the style with `\usepackage{f1000_styles}` it would work, as this would set the \makeatletter generally. But it doesn't work if you copy the content of the style in some preamble.

Comment: Ah, thanks again! I didn't fully understand the difference between usepackage and include in this context.

Comment: you used `\include` to include the macros? never use `\include ` before `\begin{document}`